# How to make a suggestion list fully displayed on screen, only one can be selected?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm creating an application which at some point needs the user to choose between a maximum of 10 possibilities (**could be less**), what I need is something that is **displaying all suggestions** on the screen, without having to extend like regular dataList.

And I need to make sure **only one** of those **can be selected** at a time.

Something like this :

[image]

If I can make the selected one highlighted it could be even better.

If you know how to do it, I'd like your advice. No need to give me the full code of it if it bothers you, just the name of the different techs will be alright and the language associated.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could take a look at jQueryUI [Checkboxradio](https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/) element.

Comment: @kerbholz
Thank you for the advice, I understand why I have to create the code myself, but I couldn't find how to do it in the first place, and not knowing how to phrase it didn't help at finding what I needed. My apologies if my intentions weren't clear enough.

Comment: @Nick thank you very much, that's precisely what I needed, didn't think of searching in jQuery, it really will be helpful, on my way to work on it !
Thanks for the quick answer as well.

Comment: No worries. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: to begin with, I would suggest to create 7 input radio with their relative label to style as in your figure